# Weak limit of an $L^1$ sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

We have functions $f_n\in L^1$ such that $\int f_ng$ has a limit for every $g\in L^\infty$. Does there exist a function $f\in L^1$ such that the limit equals $\int fg$? I think this is not true in general (really? - why?), then can this be true if we also know that $f_n$ belong to a certain subspace of $L^1$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another way of phrasing your question: Is $L^{1}$ *weakly sequentially complete*? That is to say: does every weak Cauchy sequence in $L^1$ converge?

The answer is **yes**.

(Added: See Nate's answer for a definition of *weak Cauchy sequence* and why this "completeness" of $L^1$ may be considered surprising).

Here's an outline of the argument (I'm assuming that you're working on a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$, but that's not an essential restriction, see the end of this answer):

- First of all, it follows from the uniform boundedness theorem that the sequence $(f_{n})$ is bounded in $L^{1}$.
- Next, we can define for a measurable set $E$ a quantity
  $$\nu(E) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_{n}$$
  because the characteristic function of $E$ belongs to $L^{\infty}$.
- Then one can verify that $\nu$ is a (signed) *measure* which is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. By the Radon-Nikodym theorem it follows that $\nu(E) = \int_{E} f\,d\mu$ for a unique function (class) $f \in L^{1}$.
- Now by definition we have $\displaystyle \int f g = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_{n} g$ for all *characteristic functions* $g$. But as the characteristic functions span a dense subspace of $L^{\infty}$ we conclude that this must hold for all $g \in L^{\infty}$.

You can find the details of this argument e.g. in Dunford-Schwartz, *Linear operators I*, Theorem IV.8.6 on page 290. The assumption on $\sigma$-finiteness I made is easily removed, as is also explained there: The point is that the union of the supports of the $f_n$ is $\sigma$-finite, so we may assume that we work on a $\sigma$-finite space in the first place.

Comment: How do we verify that $\nu$ is countably additive? Why can we switch lim and sum in $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}   \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E_m} f_{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}   \int_{E_m} f_{n}$ when $E_m$'s are mutually disjoint?

Comment: Secondly, let $(g_m)$ be a norm convergent simple functions in $L^\infty$ with limit $g$, then we need to verify:
$$\int f g=\lim_{m \to \infty}\int f g_m =\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_{n} g_m=\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty} \int f_{n} g_m=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_{n} g~~?$$

The first and the last equalities follow from DCT. The second one is also easy to verify, but I don't know why the third equality holds. These details are not included in Dunford-Schwartz's book~~~

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps surprisingly, the answer is yes.

More generally, given any Banach space $X$, a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset X$ is said to be **weakly Cauchy** if, for every $\ell \in X^*$, the sequence $\{\ell(f_n)\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) is Cauchy.  If every weakly Cauchy sequence is weakly convergent, $X$ is said to be **weakly sequentially complete**.

Every reflexive Banach space is weakly sequentially complete (a nice exercise with the uniform boundedness principle).  $L^1$ is not reflexive, but it turns out to be weakly sequentially complete anyway.  This theorem can be found in P. Wojtaszczyk, *Banach spaces for analysts*, as Corollary 14 on page 140.  It works for $L^1$ over an arbitrary measure space.

Comment: Many thanks to you too.