# Let $X$ be a normed space. If $X$ is weakly sequentially complete, then $X$ is reflexive.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a normed space. If $X$ is weakly sequentially complete, show that $X$ is reflexive.

And my effort is to show the closed unit ball of X is weakly compact. But I am stuck. Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true.  [$L^1$ is weakly sequentially complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40920/weak-limit-of-an-l1-sequence) but not reflexive.

For the special case of $\ell^1$ this can be proved as a corollary of [Schur's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208898/schurs-theorem-in-ell1-weak-convergence-of-x-n-is-the-same-as-convergenc) that a sequence in $\ell^1$ converges weakly iff it converges in norm.  See Proposition 2.3.12 of *Albiac, Fernando; Kalton, Nigel J.*, [**Topics in Banach space theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-31557-7), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 233. Cham: Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-31555-3/hbk; 978-3-319-31557-7/ebook). xx, 508 p. (2016). [ZBL1352.46002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1352.46002). [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C&lpg=PA38&ots=ZsNRyV7gQc&dq=weakly%20sequentially%20cauchy&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q=weakly%20sequentially%20cauchy&f=false)

Comment: This is very helpful!! Thank you!! By the way, what if we add a condition to make $X$ reflexive what condition can be added here?